# LiveData observer onChanged is not called

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to use Room database in my Quiz application.
I couldn't get list of questions from database. here is the code I'm using :

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_exam, container, false);

    queViewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(QueViewModel.class);

    queViewModel.getQuizList(examType).observe(this, new Observer<List<QueEnt>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<QueEnt> queEnts) {

            Log.e(TAG, "onChanged is called!"); // this line never shows in the Logcat 
            questionsList2 = queEnts;
        }
    });
```

and this is the ViewModel :

```
public class QueViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
private QueRepository repository;
private LiveData<List<QueEnt>> quesList;

public QueViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);

    repository=new QueRepository(application);
    quesList=repository.getQues();
}

public void insert(QueEnt queEnt){
    repository.insert(queEnt);
}
public void delete(QueEnt queEnt){
    repository.delete(queEnt);
}

public LiveData<List<QueEnt>> getQuizList(int examtype){

    Log.e(TAG,"returning a list"); // this appears in the Logcat

    return quesList;
}
}
```

The error I get is

> Invalid index 0, size is 0

on questionsList2 , of course because the list was never populated. The onChanged method is not called,  as it seems from the Logcat. 
How can I fix this ?

Edit : 
QueRepository file:

```
public class QueRepository {
private QueDao queDao;
private LiveData<List<QueEnt>> ques;

public QueRepository(Application application) {
    QueDatabase database = QueDatabase.getInstance(application);
    queDao = database.queDao();
    ques = queDao.getQuesAll();
}

public void insert(QueEnt queEnt) {
    new InsertQAsync(queDao).execute(queEnt);
}

public void update(QueEnt queEnt) {
    new UpdateQAsync(queDao).execute(queEnt);
}

public void delete(QueEnt queEnt) {
    new DeleteQAsync(queDao).execute(queEnt);
}


public LiveData<List<QueEnt>> getQues() {

    return ques;
}

private static class InsertQAsync extends AsyncTask<QueEnt, Void, Void> {
    private QueDao queDao;

    private InsertQAsync(QueDao queDao) {
        this.queDao = queDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(QueEnt... queEnts) {
        queDao.insert(queEnts[0]);
        return null;
    }
}

private static class UpdateQAsync extends AsyncTask<QueEnt, Void, Void> {
    private QueDao queDao;

    private UpdateQAsync(QueDao queDao) {
        this.queDao = queDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(QueEnt... queEnts) {
        queDao.update(queEnts[0]);
        return null;
    }
}

private static class DeleteQAsync extends AsyncTask<QueEnt, Void, Void> {
    private QueDao queDao;

    private DeleteQAsync(QueDao queDao) {
        this.queDao = queDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(QueEnt... queEnts) {
        queDao.delete(queEnts[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

And QueDao :

```
@Dao
public interface QueDao {

@Insert
void insert(QueEnt queEnt);

@Update
void update(QueEnt queEnt);

@Delete
void delete(QueEnt queEnt);

@Query("SELECT * FROM questions LIMIT 30" )
LiveData<List<QueEnt>> getQuesAll();

}
```

And Database :

```
@Database(entities = {QueEnt.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class QueDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

public static QueDatabase instance;


public static synchronized QueDatabase getInstance(Context context) {

    if (instance == null) {
        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), QueDatabase.class, "que_database")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .addCallback(roomCallback)
                .build();
    }
    return instance;
}

public abstract QueDao queDao();


private static RoomDatabase.Callback roomCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onCreate(db);
        new PopulateDbAsync(instance).execute();
    }
};

private static class PopulateDbAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private QueDao queDao;

    private PopulateDbAsync(QueDatabase db) {
        queDao = db.queDao();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        queDao.insert(new QueEnt(91, 93, "Question 1?", "   Answer 1", "Answer2 ", "Answer 3 ", " Answer4   ", 2, 2, 1,0,0,0,0,0,"","","","",""));

        queDao.insert(new QueEnt(93, 95, "Question 2?", "   Answer 1", "Answer2 ", "Answer 3 ", " Answer4   ", 3, 2, 4,0,0,0,0,0,"","","","",""));
             return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: onChanged gets called when you set/post the value to livedata.

Comment: The difference between my code and the tutorial was that i didn't use a recyclerview, . But there are no post or set value instructions there...

Comment: How does your DAO look like? How does the repository access it?

Comment: We know nothing about `QueRepository` so we cannot possibly answer this question.

Comment: I've added all relevant files ... please check ..

Comment: God help me. ..

Comment: Try to reinstall app and check again, Your code is working on my side.